# Installing Homebrew error: (35) error:1407742E:SSL

Tags: macos, terminal, installation, homebrew

I am trying to install Homebrew on my Macbook running OS X 10.6 When I tried to install Homebrew, it gave me this error:

```
curl: (35) error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
Failed during: /bin/bash -o pipefail -c '/usr/bin/curl -fsSL github.com/Homebrew/brew/… | /usr/bin/tar xz -m --strip 1'
```

I have searched this on Google, and I got 0 results.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: By the way, I think it has something to do with my os because it is really old.

Comment: Try to upgrade curl. Which version are you using?